# jax-ws @XmlRootElement not generating root element name

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws

I have created a sample jax-ws project in my eclipse.

below is the code which has Interface,Imp class and Helper class

**Interface :**

```
@WebService

public interface HelloWorld
{

    @WebMethod(operationName="getString") 
    @WebResult(name="Result")
    Helper getHelloWorldAsString(@WebParam(name="input")String str); 
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.test.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld
{

    @Override
    public Helper getHelloWorldAsString(String str) {

        Helper h = new Helper();
        String[] str1 = {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"};
        h.setTempValue(str1);


        return h;
    }
}
```

**Helper:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TypeCode")
@XmlType(name = "TypeCode")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

    public class Helper 
    {
        @XmlElement(name="value")
        private String[] tempValue;

        public String[] getTempValue() {
            return tempValue;
        }

        public void setTempValue(String[] tempValue) {
            this.tempValue = tempValue;
        }   
    }
```

When i deploy above code and send request i am seeing the response as below :

```
<ns2:getStringResponse xmlns:ns2="http://test.com/">
         <Result>
            <value>ABC</value>
            <value>DEF</value>
            <value>GHI</value>
         </Result>
      </ns2:getStringResponse>
```

The above response has the root element as 'Result' but i declared `@XmlRootElement(name = "TypeCode")` in Helper class . My question is why there is no marshaling on 'TypeCode'  as root element instead of 'Result'. Is jax-ws ignores `@XmlRootElement` and goes with `@WebResult`?

Comment: please let me know if someone has solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

With your example you answer your own question.

When the response is created the result element always as the defined name for the method result, that is why there is a @WebResult annotation.

If you don't specify a return name, it will be 'return' by default. In this element you will have one for each field of the result object.

In your case, and because you have a list, jaxb marshal this to a sequence of sub elements, without a name for the list.